# Fermion mass Higgs mechanism

Tags: mass, standard-model, fermions, higgs

How does a fermion, like an electron, get its mass through the Higgs-mechanism? Can someone explain me this with formulas (Lagrangian)?

I know that the Yukawa interaction has something to do with this, is that right?

Maybe when I'm right, there is a term:

$$g \bar{\Psi} \Phi \Psi?$$

Comment: You're right. Since this is very standard material, let me first refer you to wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model_%28mathematical_formulation%29#The_Higgs_mechanism, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_interaction so you get can a feeling for what happens.

Comment: And if I'm right again first there is a term g bar psi phi psi. Through the spontaneous symmetry breaking the yukawa term become g phi_0 bar psi psi. And phi_0 is the vacuum expectation value of the higgs field. g and phi_0 are the mass m_f of the fermion, right?

Comment: Roughly yes, but in the Standard Model the interaction couples different fields, so the total Yukawa coupling is of the form $\sum_{ij}  c_{ij} \bar \psi_i \phi_0 \psi_j$ where $c_{ij}$ is a matrix of c-numbers.

Comment: And can you please explain me, how exactly a fermion (for example a electron) get mass through the higgs-mechanism?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69056/relation-of-higgs-couplings-to-masses-of-fundamental-particles and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70585/why-some-particles-interact-with-the-higgs-field-and-others-dont

Comment: Before the symmetry breaking the Yukawa term (coupling of the higgs field with the fermion field) looks g bar psi phi psi, right? And after the symmetry breaking there is g phi_0 bar psi psi==> this is the mass term, right?

Comment: The best simple explanation I have seen is Matt Strassler's series of articles [here](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/how-the-higgs-field-works-with-math/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is about the "the 5-th force."

As you said the Yukawa term introducing the interaction between scalar field $\Phi$ and fermion $\Psi$ field:
$$g \bar{\Psi} \Phi \Psi$$

The [Higgs mechanism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17944/how-does-the-higgs-mechanism-work) causes the $\Phi$ field condense at a classical expectation value (**v.e.v**: vacuum expectation value), due to the Higgs potential $U(\Phi)$, so $\Phi$ tend to find a classical minimum, which causes:

$$\Phi(x,t) \to \langle \Phi \rangle=m$$

as a fix value $m$. You can imagine this process as originally $\Phi(x,t)$ is a field variable free to have any real/complex values at any spacetime $(x,t)$ point due to quantum fluctuation. However, the Higgs mechanism causes $\langle \Phi \rangle=m$ finding a (local) classical stable minimum value of the potential $U(\Phi)$.

The remarkable result is that $\Phi(x,t)$ semi-classically now have to take the fix value at $m$ at any spacetime point! (**This is the remarkable fact of the 5-th force: Higgs field introduces mass to fermions i.e. quarks, leptons, in the Standard Model.** Some people coin the name the 5-th force - a different mechanism from the 4 fundamental forces.)

**Add**: Some people like to think about **(fermions,W$^{\pm}$,Z$^{0}$ bosons) particles moving in the ocean of Higgs fields**, thus (fermion,W,Z) particles become massive due to the buoyancy force effects in the Higgs ocean.

The mass $M$ of fermion fields now can be read as

$$g \bar{\Psi} \Phi \Psi \to (g\cdot m) \bar{\Psi}  \Psi=M \bar{\Psi}  \Psi $$
with fermion mass $M=g\langle \Phi \rangle=g\cdot m$.

Note that now Fermion mass takes the fixed value at $g \langle \Phi \rangle$, BUT there is quantum fluctuation around the v.e.v. ($\langle \Phi \rangle+\delta \Phi $) to cause fermion field interacting with the Higgs fluctuation $\delta \Phi $. You can draw a Feynman diagram to compute its effect.

Comment: I have still one question. m is in your answer the vacuum expectation value of the higgs-field? And then g*m is the mass of the fermion?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. You are right. ps. Some people like to think about **(fermion,W,Z) particles moving in the ocean of Higgs fields**, (fermion,W,Z) particles become massive due to the buoyancy force effects in the Higgs ocean. It is pretty cute, and which description is helpful and imaginative in some way. :-)

Comment: Regarding the idea with the higgs ocean and the buoyancy. This is a imagninative description, but it is not the 100 % right  description. The 100 % correct description is your answer with the Yukawa interaction term, right?

Comment: Yes, I agree. Higgs ocean is just a hand-waving way to explain in the manner for popular science.

Comment: And your answer with the Yukawa interaction term is the 100 % correct answer in particle science?

Comment: Yes as far as I know. ps. I study particle physics theory when I was at MIT CTP.

Comment: Let me say thanks for your answers. You helped me very much. I have still one question: I can calculate the mass of the fermion as a product of g (vacuum expectation value) and the Yukawa coupling constant (how much the higgs field interacts with the fermion species) when the Yukawa coupling constant is known. Is that right?

Comment: you are very welcome. :-) please Check [peskin and schroeder](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Quantum-Theory-Frontiers-Physics/dp/0201503972) chap.11.1; chap.20.1, 20.2; if you still have questions. ps. g is not vacuum expectation value. g is the Yukawa coupling.

Comment: edit: I can calculate the mass of the fermion as a product of m (vacuum expectation value) and the Yukawa coupling constant g (how much the higgs field interacts with the fermion species) when the Yukawa coupling constant is known.

Comment: I have improved my last answer.I can calculate the mass of the fermion as a product of m (vacuum expectation value) and the Yukawa coupling constant g (how much the higgs field interacts with the fermion species) when the Yukawa coupling constant is known. Is it right now?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly correct. :)