# Do quantum fields interact in a vacuum state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

Interacting quantum fields (for example, electromagnetic and electron-positron) in a vacuum state (without real particles) continue to interact, or become free?

Answer (score 2):

The dynamics of the theory do not depend on the state. So if the Hamiltonian contains interaction terms, these terms are still there in a vacuum.

Here's a way you could quantify the effect of the interactions. Imagine you need to compute a 2-point correlation function between a field $\phi_1$ at spacetime point $\{x_1,t_1\}$ and $\phi_2$ at $\{x_2,t_2\}$ in the vacuum state. If we work in the Heisenberg picture, we will need to use the full interacting Hamiltonian to evolve $t_1$ to $t_2$ to compare the fields at the same time. Explicitly, the correlator can be written as

\begin{equation}
\langle 0 | \phi_1(x_1,t_1) \phi_2(x_2,t_2) | 0 \rangle = \langle 0 | U(t_1,t_2)^\dagger \phi_1(x_1,t_2) U(t_1,t_2) \phi_2(x_2,t_2) | 0 \rangle
\end{equation}
where $U(t_1,t_2)$ is the time evolution operator
\begin{equation}
U(t_1,t_2) = T e^{- i \int_{t_1}^{t_2} Ht}
\end{equation}
where $T$ is the time ordering symbol, and $H$ is the **full interacting Hamiltonian** including all interaction terms.

Comment: It is clear, that is, they interact.

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress just curious your representation doesn't make sense right. because you will need a propagator to push particle from x1 to x2.

Comment: Your comment is probably not addressed to me.

Comment: @JonDu Which  representation is correct? Do quantum fields stop interacting in a vacuum state?

Comment: I think what I wrote is correct. I showed how the interaction Hamiltonian appears in a generic correlation function. You might want to add additional steps in a given application but I just wrote what was needed to answer the question.

Comment: Quantum fields do interact in a vacuum state. Another manifestation of this (besides what I wrote above) is that the vacuum state itself gets renormalized between an interacting and free theory; look up "vacuum bubbles."

Comment: @Andrew I also think your answer is correct. It is strange to imagine a situation in which the interacting fields suddenly become free in a vacuum state.

Comment: "So if the Hamiltonian contains interaction terms, these terms are still there in a vacuum.". Does not that mean that the Feynman diagrams for  *measurable  states*  have to include  *real* incoming four vectors, even for the vacuum interactions?

Comment: @annav I am not sure I understand the question, but here is an attempt. The Feynman diagrams relevant for the vacuum state are "vacuum bubbles" which renormalize the vacuum state. These diagrams lead to the cosmological constant problem, but otherwise has no directly observable consequence as far as I know. But, they are important for setting up the formalism of quantum field theory consistently.

Comment: In the sentense I quote , my observation is that the φ  you have in your formula does not allow writing independent  from incoming particles loops in the vacuum, it's mathematical expression needs the propagator for measurable  interactions ( as loop corrections are) .

Comment: You don't necessarily need to interpret vacuum correlation functions in terms of particles. We could be looking at correlation functions in inflation, for example. I am a bit worried this is going to descend into a semantic argument. Honestly I am not 100% sure how to make this question well-posed, but there is no sense in which you can say the interactions are turned off in the vacuum state.

Comment: @annav The key word is measurable. Vacuum fluctuations are not directly measurable, but they have an indirect effect. Therefore, it is impossible not to take them into account. And I repeat, it will be strange to imagine a situation in which the interacting fields in a vacuum state become free. Can you write a Hamiltonian for such a system?